# Mechanical Turk Java API: Creating HITS in Loop

Tags: mechanicalturk

I have question in form of XML and I create them in loop for each question. I then create HIT in each loop giving input question file. But then each time HIT is created the url seems to be same and my previous HIT gets overwritten. Any help is appreciated.

In below code Iam referring to

String url = service.getWebsiteURL() + "/mturk/preview?groupId=" + hit.getHITTypeId()

where url that is formed is same for all HITS.

How can i create different HIT url?

```
HITQuestion question = new HITQuestion(questionFile);
HITProperties props = new HITProperties(propertyFile);
//Creating the HIT and loading it into Mechanical Turk
HIT hit = service.createHIT(null, // HITTypeId 
          props.getTitle(), 
          props.getDescription(), 
          props.getKeywords(), // keywords 
          question.getQuestion(),
          props.getRewardAmount(), props.getAssignmentDuration(),
          props.getAutoApprovalDelay(), props.getLifetime(),
          props.getMaxAssignments(), props.getAnnotation(), 
          props.getQualificationRequirements(),
          null // responseGroup
        );
System.out.println("Created HIT: " + hit.getHITId());\

System.out.println("You may see your HIT with HITTypeId '" + hit.getHITTypeId() + "' here: ");

System.out.println(service.getWebsiteURL() + "/mturk/preview?groupId=" + hit.getHITTypeId());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create HITs with the same qualifications and payment, they appear under the same groupid. When you complete as a Worker one HIT, another will then become available. If you log onto the Requester view on mturk.com you will be able to see all your HITs individually

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, when i log in as worker Iam able to see all the differnent HITS by using Skip HIT and once I accept it I can start working on it. It looked differnt to me as first I had created HIT using template and now did it using java API. But i think its fine as all the HITS are seen even if the URL is same.